# Create custom object array with jQuery.map() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

[image]

I have table as seen above and I want to create a custom array to pass values.

Currently I am using the following lines of code:

```
var arr = $('input[type=text].editfield').map(function () {
        return this;
    }).get();
    var objArr = jQuery.map(arr, function (i) {
        return {
            myDate: i.parentElement.previousSibling.previousSibling.previousSibling.previousSibling.previousSibling.previousSibling.childNodes[0].textContent,
            myValue: i.value
        }
    }).get();
```

and I expect to have an array of objects of all items in my grid with Date and Value as properties respectively.

But something is wrong and I can not solve. For example the code above says "***jQuery.map(...).get is not a function***"

How can I correct my code to perform the correct action?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no need to use .get() on the static [jQuery.map()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) function, it returns a proper array, while the plugin method [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/) returns a jQuery object on which you have to call [.get()](http://api.jquery.com/get/) to get an array.

---

Also there is no need to use 2 loops,

```
var objArr = $('input[type=text].editfield').map(function (idx, i) {
    //the element selection used here is cruel, if you can share the html used we can help you to clean it
    return {
        // you can try myDate: $(this).parent().prevAll().eq(5).text() - not testable without the html and what is the expected output
        myDate: i.parentElement.previousSibling.previousSibling.previousSibling.previousSibling.previousSibling.previousSibling.childNodes[0].textContent,
        myValue: i.value
    };
}).get();
```

Comment: That was the exact answer I have been looking for. Thank you very much.

Comment: Also thank you very much for the improvement suggested in the comments.These two both worked well for me.